# get max and min values based on conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, min

I have a dataframe like this

| count | A | B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 4900 | 0 | 0 |
| yes | 1000 | 1000 | 0 |
| sum_yes | 5900 | 1000 | 0 |
| yes | 4000 | 0 | 0 |
| yes | 1000 | 0 | 0 |
| sum_yes | 5000 | 0 | 0 |

I want result like this that is calculate max of column A and B only for rows where 'count' = 'sum_yes' if value of B =0 otherwise  calculate minimum

| count | A | B | Total |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| yes | 4900 | 0 | 0 |
| yes | 1000 | 1000 | 0 |
| sum_yes | 5900 | 1000 | 1000 |
| yes | 4000 | 0 | 0 |
| yes | 1000 | 0 | 0 |
| sum_yes | 5000 | 0 | 5000 |

I have tried this so far:

```
df['Total'] = [df[['A', 'B']].where(df['count'] == 'sum_yes').max(axis=0) if 
                   'B'==0 else df[['A', 'B']]
                   .where(df['count'] == 'sum_yes').min(axis=0)]
```

But I am getting ValueError The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()

Any idea how to solve this

Comment: Total in the first count row with 'sum_yes' should be 1000 i.e. min(5900, 1000) but youw show 0.

Comment: yes you are right ,corrected the values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `numpy.where`:

```
new_values = np.where((df["count"] == "sum_yes") & (df.B == 0),
                       df.loc[:, ["A", "B"]].max(1),
                       df.loc[:, ["A", "B"]].min(1),
                      )

df.assign(Total = new_values)


     count     A     B  Total
0      yes  4900     0      0
1      yes  1000     0      0
2  sum_yes  5900  1000   1000
3      yes  4000  1000   1000
4      yes  1000     0      0
5  sum_yes  5000     0   5000
```

Comment: Numpy where is similar to an if else clause... The first line is the condition, if the condition is met then the second line is selected, if it fails then the third line. Second and third lines simply pick the max or min of A and B